# Getting the href attribute of an image with Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, ios, href, src

New to Javascript, really need some help!

Now I have an image in a HTML page, like this:

```
<a class="p" href="http://www.abc.com"><img src="http://www.abc.com/logo.jpg" alt="" /></a>
```

And get the image element by:

```
var e.document.elementFromPoint(x,y);
```

When I clicked on the image, I can get the src attribute or offset attributes successfully by:

```
e.src or e.offsetHeight
```

However, it returns NULL when I use:

```
return e.href;
```

So how can I get the correct href attribute (http://www.abc.com) ??

Thanks,

Peak

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The href is not a propery of the image but of the A element.

You can acces it by using the `.parentNode` propery of the image. as it is its direct parent.

Answer (score 3):

You can get the parent node of the `img`, which is the `a` using [parentNode](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/DOM/Node.parentNode):

```
return e.parentNode.href;
```

Answer (score 1):

The href atrribute is only available on `a` and `link` elements. So you just need to get the parent node of the image:

```
var thea=e.parentNode;
if(thea.nodeName.toLowerCase()=="a"){ //If the tag is a hyperlink
    return thea.href;
}else{
    return ""; //Return an empty string if the image is not inside a hyperlink
}
```

Ad@m