# How to grab image's parent link?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I have a Chrome extension that finds an image. I want to print the link you go to when you click that image. For instance, in this case, I want to print "https://politi.co/3ef3fyd?fbclid=IwAR0pLY2x8H5do4N_WBudKJUMzDx0qlBfeOWVVjN2hrbutdwf9ZXq2vIOKbc."

I tried parentNode following [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6452212/getting-the-href-attribute-of-an-image-with-javascript) SO suggestion. "There's a defined image here" prints fine. But then I get an error in the next line: "TypeError: Cannot read property 'href' of undefined."

**Javascript**

```
    var image = $(uCW).find('[src^="https://external"]').attr("src");
    console.log(image);

    if(typeof image !== "undefined")
    {
          console.log("there's a defined image here");
          var ilink = image.parentNode.href;
          console.log("ilink", ilink);
    }
```

**Update**:

Now I'm using:

```
var cat = $("image").closest('a').href;
console.log("cat", cat)
```

But it's just printing "undefined."

**HTML**

```
<a href="https://politi.co/3ef3fyd?fbclid=IwAR0pLY2x8H5do4N_WBudKJUMzDx0qlBfeOWVVjN2hrbutdwf9ZXq2vIOKbc" aria-describedby="u_fetchstream_3_7" aria-label="Tara Reade’s lawyer drops her as a client" tabindex="-1" target="_blank" rel="noopener nofollow" data-lynx-mode="asynclazy" data-nguardprocessed="true" data-lynx-uri="https://l.facebook.com/l.php?u=https%3A%2F%2Fpoliti.co%2F3ef3fyd%3Ffbclid%3DIwAR0pLY2x8H5do4N_WBudKJUMzDx0qlBfeOWVVjN2hrbutdwf9ZXq2vIOKbc&amp;h=AT2KhFxAof_9rmralxQQBdP5e1HxxUdkL-Bu8y09XvpSAcOGDaIhyU7SRJ9IeDsJhrXKMOmyUZ6WDBPiAJrhkeMQ_yaWEFhFVHlFXuyIj5XXQugS5BaFuJO3U3kR4Lk1wKEUq_SPGmWbnhAfHv7Zh3vu5tIlhfZuQZXT5wnGk4U">
   <div class="accessible_elem inlineBlock" id="u_fetchstream_3_7">
      <div class="nguard-widget" style="display: inline-block; position: relative;">
         <div>
            <div class="sc-VigVT hgSSpT">
               <div class="sc-jTzLTM fuPExf">
                  <svg class="newsguard_icon" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 49 64">
                     <g>
                        <rect fill="#fff" x="5.11" y="11.06" width="40.4" height="31.66"></rect>
                     </g>
                     <g>
                        <path fill="#42b149" fill-rule="evenodd" d="M49,0H0V24.07C0,40.86,0,52,22.79,63.18l1.67.82,1.66-.82C48.54,52,49,40.86,49,24.07ZM22.86,40.23a2.35,2.35,0,0,1-3.45,0L7.33,28.37a2.47,2.47,0,0,1,0-3.39l3.54-3.4a2.15,2.15,0,0,1,1.67-.75,2.45,2.45,0,0,1,1.77.75l6.83,6.76L36.9,12.77A2.45,2.45,0,0,1,38.67,12a2.14,2.14,0,0,1,1.67.75l3.54,3.39a2.49,2.49,0,0,1,0,3.4Z"></path>
                     </g>
                  </svg>
               </div>
            </div>
         </div>
      </div>
      Her attorney said the decision “is by no means a reflection on whether then-Senator Biden sexually assaulted Ms. Reade.”
   </div>
   <div class="_6l- __c_">
      <div class="uiScaledImageContainer _6m5 fbStoryAttachmentImage" style="width:514px;height:268.42222222222px;"><img class="scaledImageFitWidth img" src="https://external-ort2-2.xx.fbcdn.net/safe_image.php?d=AQB8m91AABOjBxLI&amp;w=540&amp;h=282&amp;url=https%3A%2F%2Fstatic.politico.com%2F7c%2F4a%2Fc9f2023e43c0aa8055e248e1ffee%2F200522-tara-reade-ap-773.jpg&amp;cfs=1&amp;upscale=1&amp;fallback=news_d_placeholder_publisher&amp;_nc_hash=AQBjEY6wVpUxS5-r" data-src="https://external-ort2-2.xx.fbcdn.net/safe_image.php?d=AQB8m91AABOjBxLI&amp;w=540&amp;h=282&amp;url=https%3A%2F%2Fstatic.politico.com%2F7c%2F4a%2Fc9f2023e43c0aa8055e248e1ffee%2F200522-tara-reade-ap-773.jpg&amp;cfs=1&amp;upscale=1&amp;fallback=news_d_placeholder_publisher&amp;_nc_hash=AQBjEY6wVpUxS5-r" style="top:0px;" alt="" width="514" height="269" aria-label="No photo description available."></div>
   </div>
</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

This will give you array of all links around images:

```js
$$('img').map((el) => el.closest('a'))
  .filter(Boolean)
  .map((link) => link.href)
```

You can reduce scope of search like this:

```js
Object.values(root.getElementsByTagName('img'))
  .map((el) => el.closest('a'))
  .filter(Boolean)
  .map((link) => link.href)
```

where `root` is some DOM element

Comment: Thanks, but I'm trying to grab a specific link, not any nearby one — there can be a lot of nearby links depending on the div, and it would be hard to automate selecting the correct one from a list. (for instance, the link to the actual image file will always be the closest link, but that's not what I'm looking for)

Comment: so what is your source from which you start looking for link? That uCW? Or you just have image url?

Comment: The uCW yes — it's inside that. It's a div that contains both the image, the url, and more stuff I didn't include since it's pretty big.

Comment: you can reduce scope of search as in second example

Comment: I'm not sure how I'd filter it though, since links are different (come from different websites and look totally different) each time. Is there no way to find the link you get directed to when you click the image?

Comment: the link you are directed to after clicking any part of website is the url in href in closest a ancestor of that web fragment at least if there are no javascripts involved that would change that behaviour. So basicaly if you have image you look up his ancestor a element and read its href that should be what you are looking for at least befor any redirections put ontop of that link in routing phase.

Comment: Why do I need to find any 'img'? Can't I just use the image I've already found? And how would I print what I found? So far, I keep getting "undefined."

Comment: If you already have image you can just do that part with finding link. But from what you wrote that wasn't clear that you already have it so I assumed you have some DOM element.

Comment: Made an update (included in post), but I'm still getting undefined. "image" is the variable name for my image.

Comment: this error may mean there is no link above image so you are trying to request url from not existing element thats why in my example I am using filter to remove all images that don't have links above them in DOM structure

Comment: There definitely is a link there ... you can see it in the HTML i posted

Comment: Try creating interactive example on stackblitz only what i see now is you have `$("image")` and not `$("img")`